# How can I shadow the textual content of gatsby themes?

Tags: reactjs, themes, gatsby, static-site

I'd like to customize this gatsby theme https://github.com/NK-WebDev/gatsby-theme-teranova ([live demo](https://nifty-sinoussi-4a8cab.netlify.com/)). The structure of the theme's and the demo's source code seems to be generic for gatsby themes.

The structure of the demo source code is as follows:

```
demo
  src/pages
    index.mdx
  static/images
    banner.png
    favicon.png
    logo.svg
  gatsby-config.js
  package.json
```

The structure of the theme source code is as follows:

```
gatsby-theme-teranova
  data
    content
      services
        branding.mdx
        logo-design.mdx
        marketing.mdx
        web-design.mdx
      about.jpg
      about.mdx
      banner.jpg
      intro.mdx
    index.js
  src
    components
      about.js
      contact.js
      service.js
      services.js
      ...
    pages
      index.mdx
    theme.js
  static/images
    banner.png
    favicon.png
    logo.svg
  gatsby-config.js
  index.js
  package.json
```

I thought the textual content of a theme webpage is defined in *.mdx files (here: `gatsby-theme-teranova/data/content/about.mdx`, `gatsby-theme-teranova/data/content/contact.mdx`, etc.) and is rendered with corresponding *.js files of the theme (here: `gatsby-theme-teranova/src/components/about.js`, `gatsby-theme-teranova/src/components/contact.js`, etc.). There is just `demo/src/pages/index.mdx` in the demo. Means the theme buildin content is not modified in the demo. I expected that placing custom text content in `demo/data/content/about.mdx`, etc. would shadow the corresponding webpage content. But when running `gatsby develop` it does not. It is just ignored. How is done shadowing of the webpage text correctly?

BTW: To me it is not clear if shadowing in the demo is done correctly. As long as banner.png, favicon.png and logo.svg of the demo do not differ from the theme's files they would not have to be included in the demo source explicitly.